# The kafka script kafka-consumer-group.sh throws timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster running with 3 brokers.

```
<node-ip>:10092 //broker-0
<node-ip>:10093 //broker-1
<node-ip>:10094 //broker-2
```

The broker-1 `<node-ip>:10093` is in a not-ready state(due to some readiness failure). But other 2 brokers are running fine.

But when I use the script `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` with a running broker address as bootstrap-server, I get the following error.

```
kafka@mirror-maker-0:/opt/kafka/bin$ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server <node-ip>:10094 --describe --group c2-c1-consumer-group --state
[2022-03-14 10:24:16,008] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/<node-ip>:10093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-14 10:24:17,086] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/<node-ip>:10093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-14 10:24:18,206] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/<node-ip>:10093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-14 10:24:19,458] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/<node-ip>:10093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=DESCRIBE_GROUPS)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=DESCRIBE_GROUPS)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.$anonfun$describeConsumerGroups$1(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:543)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedMapOps.map(StrictOptimizedMapOps.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedMapOps.map$(StrictOptimizedMapOps.scala:27)
    at scala.collection.convert.JavaCollectionWrappers$AbstractJMapWrapper.map(JavaCollectionWrappers.scala:309)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeConsumerGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:542)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.collectGroupsState(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:620)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:373)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.run(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:72)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:59)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeGroups(api=DESCRIBE_GROUPS)
```

Could someone please help me to understand

1. Why is it connecting to the non mentioned broker(log shows 10093 but I passed :10094)?
2. Is there any solution to use only the mentioned bootstrap-servers?

One more thing is,

When I run `kafka-topics.sh` with the running broker address as bootstrap-server, it returns the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue. I was able to read the topics but I cannot list, describe the groups. I solved the issue by adding a large timeout. Can you please also try putting a large timeout?

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --command-config kafka.properties --bootstrap-server brokers  --group group --describe --timeout 100000